# How to Sort a Class List that contain both of double and string data

Tags: c#, class, sorting, sql-order-by, tryparse

Person class:

```
class Person
    {
        public string ID;
        public string Name;
        public string PClass;
        public string Age;
        public string Sex;
        public string Survived;
        public string SexCode;
        public Person(string id,string name,string pclass,string age,string sex,
            string survived,string sexcode)
        {
            ID = id;
            Name = name;
            PClass = pclass;
            Age = age;
            Sex = sex;
            Survived = survived;
            SexCode = sexcode;
        }
```

My program code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("titanic.csv");
            data = data.Skip(1).ToArray();
            List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
            List<Person> personList_name = new List<Person>();
            List<Person> personList_pclass = new List<Person>();
            List<Person> personList_age = new List<Person>();
            List<Person> personList_sex = new List<Person>();
            List<Person> personList_id = new List<Person>();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] temp = Regex.Split(data[i], ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
                Person person = new Person(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2],temp[3],
                temp[4], temp[5], temp[6]);
                personList.Add(person);

            }

            personList_name = personList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
            personList_pclass = personList.OrderBy(z => z.PClass).ToList();
            personList_sex = personList.OrderBy(w => w.Sex).ToList();
            int id_;
            int age_;
            personList_age = personList.OrderBy(y => int.TryParse(y.Age, out age_)).ToList();
            //personList_id = personList.OrderByDescending(int.TryParse(ID, out number)).ToList();
            personList_id = personList.OrderBy(o => int.TryParse(o.ID, out id_)).ToList();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Please select your filtring method:\n" +
                    "1-By Name\n2-By Pclass\n3-By Age\n4-By Sex\n5-By ID\n Press -1 to quit.");
                string selection = Console.ReadLine();
                if (selection == "-1")
                {
                    break;
                }

                        Console.WriteLine(("{0,-10}{1,70}{2,20}{3,20}{4,20}{5,20}{6,20}"), item.ID.Trim('"'), item.Name.Trim('"'), item.PClass.Trim('"')
                            , item.Age, item.Sex.Trim('"'), item.Survived.Trim('"')
                            , item.SexCode.Trim('"'));
                    }
                 }
                if (selection == "3")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(("{0,-10}{1,70}{2,20}{3,20}{4,20}{5,20}{6,20}"), "ID", "NAME", "PCLASS", "AGE", "SEX", "SURVIVED", "SEXCODE");
                    foreach (var item in personList_age)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(("{0,-10}{1,70}{2,20}{3,20}{4,20}{5,20}{6,20}"), item.ID.Trim('"'), item.Name.Trim('"'), item.PClass.Trim('"')
                            , item.Age, item.Sex.Trim('"'), item.Survived.Trim('"')
                            , item.SexCode.Trim('"'));

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I am able to sort string data from CSV file such as Name, but for age and ID I cannot obtain the correct order (either ascending or descending) 
I have searched a lot about this problem. Tried to use Icomparable and Tryparse 
but without any positive result. The problem is that Orderby deals with age and ID as string. But if I define Age and ID as double or int I will have "cannot convert" while defining temp array. Any helpful suggestion or solution PLEASE?

This is what happens when I order according to Age for example. It seems still ordering according to ID! 
[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [up-00.com](https://a.up-00.com/2017/11/151108704975922.png))</sub>

Comment: Wall of code is too hard to read (especially with excessive vertical spacing). Reduce to a *minimal* example showing your problem.

Comment: Don't create a bunch of new lists and then assign over them. `var personList_name =new List<Person>(); personList_name = personList.OrderBy(...);` you unnecessarily allocate a new list and then overwrite it with the second line there. Also, your `OrderBy`s with the `TryParse` in them are ordering by the result of the method which is `true`/`false` and NOT the parsed value. If they parse successfully then they get ordered by `true`; things that fail to parse get ordered by `false`. In an (ascending) ordering, `false` comes before `true`. After that the results are probably(?) random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an expression, provide a function:

```
personList_age = personList.OrderBy
(
    y => {
             int age;
             bool ok = int.TryParse(y.Age, out age);
             return ok ? age : default(int);
         }
).ToList();
```

Or to keep things clean maybe write an extension method:

```
static void int ToInt(this string input)
{
    int n;
    bool ok = int.TryParse(input, out n);
    return ok ? n : default(int);
}
```

And call like this:

```
personList_age = personList.OrderBy( y => t.Age.ToInt());
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked properly. Is it better to use Windows form application for this kind of sorting?

Comment: ASP.NET vs. Windows Forms has nothing to do with sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
personList.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.id)).ToList();
```

?

This way it should sort them by the int-value

Comment: This will cause this error shown in cmd screen "unhandled exception input string was not in a correct format"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `TryParse` returns a `bool` and not the parsed value. `OrderBy` then orders `true` vs `false`. In an ascending ordering, `false` comes *before* `true`.

If you are expecting these values to always be integers you have a few options.

The better (in my opinion) is to change those  properties in your class to integers and do your parsing in the constructor, throwing an exception if a bad value is passed (not allowing a bad `Person` to be created).

The second option would be to switch to `int.Parse` within the `OrderBy`. This only works if all the values can definitely be parsed because otherwise an exception is thrown.

If you must use `TryParse` (for example it's not guaranteed to be integer data and you can't change your class definition), you can use a multi statement lambda:

```
personList.OrderBy(person => { 
     int value; 
     return int.TryParse(person.ID, out value) ? value : -1;
});
```

You may want to chose a different value for the failure case depending on where you want them to sort. In the above case all failures would come first--though that *assumes* that  no `ID` could be negative. You could use `int.MinValue` instead. If you want them to come last you could use `int.MaxValue`--though if your `ID`s could legitimately be that large you'll have a problem (I think it is safe to assume at least that nobody will have an `age` that large).

Another option would be to filter out the failures by first using `Select` to create an anonymous type containing the data you need (successfully parsed, value if applicable and your original `Person`). Then use `Where` to filter our any values that failed to parse followed by an `OrderBy` on the parsed data. Finally use another `Select` to extract your `Person` from the anonymous type.

```
personList.Select(p => {
     int value; 
     var ok = int.TryParse(p.ID, out value);
     return new { Ok = ok, ID = value, Person = p };
})
.Where(result => result.Ok)
.OrderBy(result => result.ID)
.Select(result => result.Person);
```